# How to request the multiple resources in rest service

Tags: java, rest

I am kind of new to RESTful web services and need some help. I have service which will return a list of products. The URL looks like the following:

```
/example/product/6666,6667?expand=sellers&storeIds=2,1
```

To define this service I have this interface:

```
@Path("/example")
public interface Service {
    @GET
    @Path("/products/{pIds}")
    @Produces( "application/json" )
    public ServiceResponse<ProductsList> getProducts(
        @PathParam("pIds") String productsIds,
        @QueryParam("expand") String expand,
        @QueryParam("storeIds") String storeIds) throws Exception;
}
```

I am assuming here that I am getting the `productsIds` as a string and that I will need to manually split this string into a list of ids, with delimiter as a comma.

Is there a way to instead get the parameters as list, instead of doing manually it from my side? Or is there a library that I can use to do this in an automated way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deserialize the product id's directly into a list with some minor change to your service definition. Try this instead:

```
@Path("/example")
public interface Service {
    @GET
    @Path("/products/{pIds}")
    @Produces( "application/json" )
    public ServiceResponse<ProductsList> getProducts(
        @PathParam("pIds") List<String> productsIds,
        @QueryParam("expand") String expand,
        @QueryParam("storeIds") String storeIds) throws Exception;
}
```

Change `String productsIds` to `List<String> productsIds`.

On a side note, I would recommend passing in the product id's as a query parameter. Your URI should identify a unique resource (in this case products) and it should be stateless.

Comment: thanks for answer but my question is how does the pathparam knows the comma is a delimiter and how does path param unmarshels the request..?

Comment: Comma is the standard delimiter for JAX-RS in cases like this. And the JAX-RS provider is the one that deserializes the data into a list.

Comment: what if if i want to add "_" or ":" as my delimiter ..?how do we specify to JAX-RS that this is delimiter my new ..?

Comment: Theres no way to override the delimiter used, AFAIK. If you really want to use a custom delimiter though, I would recommend serializing to a String, then using `String.split()` in your code.

Comment: ya that was my initial thoguht...thanks a lot for your information...it really helps a lot ...:)

Comment: ..i tried this but some how it is not working..It is mapping to a list with only one element in it which has comma separated values..Let me post my code...

Comment: @Path("/example")
public interface ItemPricingService {
        @GET
 @Path("/products/{pIds}")
 @Produces( "application/json" )
 public ServiceResponse<ProductPricingList> getProducts(@PathParam("pIds") List<String> productsIds,@QueryParam("expand") String expand,@QueryParam("storeIds") String storeIds)

Comment: @swati - you might want to post a separate question - don't forget to include in it, relevant portion of code, the exact stacktrace, and/or detailed description of what is going wrong.